# Finding all elements within a region

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

If i want to find all elements that are inside a box region, what is the best way to do it as a Firefox extension? If i check all leave elements and call getBoundingClientRect(), it'd be too slow given that there can easily be more than 500 leaves on a page.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: My addon adds a layer on top, so the elements I'm interested in finding are the 2nd topmost elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `document.elementFromPoint` and visit each fifth pixel (every fifth is much faster than visiting every *single* pixel), adding each found element to an array:

```
function getElementsInRegion(x, y, width, height) {

    var elements = [],
        expando = +new Date,
        cx = x,
        cy = y,
        curEl;

    height = y + height;
    width = x + width;

    while ((cy += 5) < height) {
        cx = x;
        while (cx < width) {
            curEl = document.elementFromPoint(cx, cy);
            if ( curEl && !curEl[expando] ) {
                curEl[expando] = new Number(0);
                elements.push(curEl);
                cx += curEl.offsetWidth;
            } else {
                cx += 5;
            }
        }
    }

    return elements;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But are there ways to make document.elementFromPoint return the 2nd topmost elements instead? My addon adds another layer on top, so document.elementFromPoint would return that layer instead.

Comment: You can temporarily hide your layer (`display:none;`) and then run the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot J-P for the elementFromPoint() I was just looking for this